# Specify SSH credentials/keys in Windows Git under Jenkins user

Tags: windows, git, bash, jenkins, ssh

I am using Jenkins in our builds
So I am already using the GIT Plugin
This plugin lets me specify Jenkins credentials, where we have already specified and installed/setup SSH keys.

However at the end of the build, I'd like to git tag my repo. I am calling the git.exe command line, and I get this error on a push:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Ideally, we don't want to use another plug in, (e.g. Git Publisher), as we are trying to do more of this via our own scripts as there is a good possibility that we may not use Jenkins in the future.

Also, ideally, we don't want to install items on our build server if we don't have to.

So the question is - how can I specify ssh keys/credentials on the command line for the given 'session'?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add your Jenkins code?

Answer (score 1):

Put this in a shell script:

```
ssh -i path-to-your-private-key
```

Set the path to the shell script in `GIT_SSH` for Jenkins. `git pull` will then use that instead of plain `ssh` to access the remote repository.

Alternately you could configure ssh in `$HOME/.ssh` for the account under which Jenkins runs, but that can get tricky if your Jenkins runs as a Windows service.

Comment: Yes, it runs as a Windows Service. What is GIT_SSH?

Comment: It's an environment variable. See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables